# Directory is not copying to dse fs

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to copy folder from server to dse fs but it is gettng saved as file

```
dse fs "put file:/home/dir /"
```

Getting this error

```
IOException: is a directory
```

Is there any way to copy directory to dse filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `dse fs "cp -R file://.... /"` instead of `put`, but the `-R` flag was added only DSE 6.7. If you're on lower versions, then you'll need to write a simple script that will walk through directory & upload individual files.

another workaround, if you have a single level of files, you can use following commands:

```sh
dse fs "mkdir dir" "cp file://`pwd`/dir/* /dir/"
```

Comment: I am using 6.0.4 version and this command is not working, without R option its giving error "Unknown option -R " and without R is is again expecting a file

Comment: ah, sorry - `-R` is available in 6.7 only - tested on wrong machine

Comment: I have multiple level of files. I have written a shell script for same